# How to create link in asp.net mvc with html tags in title?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routelink

How can i create link using this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505243.aspx
html.RouteLink using html tags in title?
In result i would see something like this :

```
<a class="" href="#"><div class="someclass">1</div><div class="someotherclass"></div></a>
```

Comment: Just a reminder: HTML 4.01 specifies that <a> elements may only contain inline elements. A <div> is a block element, so it may not appear inside an <a>. HTML 5 however does allow it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not you try to use [Url.Action()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) method.. Something like this :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")" class="something"><div class="someclass">1</div><div class="someotherclass"></div></a>
```

Only suggestion. Example is written using Razor syntax, but you can also simple use it with ASPX view engine...